# select sum columns from diffrent table using linq

Tags: linq, group-by, sum

Here is my linq code..

```
( from Order o in masterRepository.Orders.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false)
                join OrderItem oi in masterRepository.OrderItems on o.OrderID equals oi.OrderID
                group oi by new {o.StoreID, o.CreatedOn.Year, o.CreatedOn.Month, StoreNmae="Test" } into g
                        select new ST_SalesOrder
                       {
                         Year = g.Key.Year,
                         Month = g.Key.Month,
                         StoreID = g.Key.StoreID,
                         StoreName = "SA",
                         SubTotal = g.Sum(o => o.SubTotal),
                         Shipping = g.Sum(o => o.ShippingPrice),
                         Tax = g.Sum(o => o.Tax),
                         TotalAmount = g.Sum(o => o.Total),
                         TotalCount = g.Sum(oi => oi.Quantity)
                         }).OrderBy("Year desc, Month desc, StoreName").ToList();
```

The thing is that..
I need to get sum data from Order table and OrderItem table.
but I can only group by using one table.

If I group o by.... then `TotalCount = g.Sum(oi => oi.Quantity)` <-- this makes error,
if I group oi by... then  `SubTotal = g.Sum(o => o.SubTotal),
                         Shipping = g.Sum(o => o.ShippingPrice),
                         Tax = g.Sum(o => o.Tax),`   <-- these make error...

what should I do!!!
please help.

Answer (score 1):

You could

```
group new { Item = oi, Order = o } by new {o.StoreID, o.CreatedOn.Year, o.CreatedOn.Month, StoreNmae="Test" } into g
```

then you could sum

```
g.Sum(o => o.Order.Total)
```

and

```
g.Sum(o => o.Item.Quantity)
```